# How to use mysql WHERE IN for two separate tables

Tags: mysql, where-in

I have two tables

**books_tbl**:

```
blocks  side-bar   top-bar
 23,45   3,15      11,56
```

**pages_tbl**:

```
id title
1  ff
3
11
15
```

I want to select the rows from `pages_tbl` where pages id has included either blocks, side-bar or tob-bar columns in `books_table`.

How to process this?

Comment: Fix your table structure. **Never** store multiple value in a single cell. See Normalization.

Comment: @GurV : This is not my own system. I'm doing some revamping according to a client. So It's hard tp change structre. Is it possible to do it using WHERE IN clause? pls advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually not a good idea to store comma separated values in a single field. If you really cannot change your data structure, you could use a query like this:

```
select p.id, p.title
from
  pages_tbl p inner join books_tbl b
  on (
    find_in_set(p.id, b.blocks)
    or find_in_set(p.id, b.side-bar)
    or find_in_set(p.id, b.top-bar)
  )
-- add where condition?
group by p.id, p.title
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider fixing your table structure. Never store multiple value in a single cell. See Normalization.

As in this case you can't, try using `find_in_set` function.

```
select
from pages_tbl p
where exists (
    select 1
    from books_tbl b
    where find_in_set(
        p.id, 
        concat(b.blocks, ',', b.side_bar, ',', b.top_bar)
        ) > 0
);
```

Remember though that this *will* be slow because the server can't use index if any.